# Why Firefox & IE breaks down my div boxes and place underneath each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 div boxes (with fixed width and dynamic height) that are set next to each other. This works fine in Chrome. But in Mozilla and IE, the boxes don't stay same, they break down themselves and sits on top of each other, what I definitely don't want to happen. Even if I minimize the window size (it happens with all browsers) the boxes break down and don't stay in the same row. I want to get rid of this problem. I want that whatever size the window have or what ever browser is used, the boxes shouldn't break down. They must still be able to fit next to each other.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dovqub9L/)

[NOTE/SIDE INFO: I have set the width of my each box 253 px because the max-width of my bosy is set as 1200px, and 253px is estimated so that they all can fit inside 1200px]

This piece of code I am working on:

.HTML:

```
<div class="box">box1box1box1box1box1<br>

</div>
<div class="box">Box2Box2Box2Box2Box2<br>


</div>
<div class="box">box3box3box3box3box3<br>

</div>
```

.CSS:

```
.box {
  display:inline-block;

  margin-top:100px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;

  margin-bottom:60px;
  margin-left:70px;
  padding:15px;

  width:253px;

  border: 4px solid gray;
  border-radius:5px;


}
```

Comment: [Looks okay to me](http://i.imgur.com/WoO6Zdz.png)...

Comment: wait a moment, let me show u my picture

Comment: onathan Sampson , since I got the answer, i will close my discussion here thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to put your content in a block-level container element with a width that's wide enough for the elements to not wrap to the next line:

http://jsfiddle.net/o8r97fhf/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">box1box1box1box1box1<br /></div>
    <div class="box">Box2Box2Box2Box2Box2<br /></div>
    <div class="box">box3box3box3box3box3<br /></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:1161px;
}
.box {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:100px;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    margin-bottom:60px;
    margin-left:70px;
    padding:15px;
    width:253px;
    border: 4px solid gray;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

The reason why it is doing this is because the <div class="box" /> elements have "display:inline-block;" - making them act more like an element such as <img /> where it has a height and width, but it is displayed inline, and if there's not enough room on one line, the elements will wrap to the next line.

Another thing you can try with the container <div /> element is to put "white-space: nowrap;" on it instead of specifying a particular width on it.

One thing I do when I'm messing around with CSS like this is, I will put a temporary "background-color:#F0F;" on the container <div /> element so I can see exactly what the dimensions look like, and what is really going on in the page.

Comment: JUST Awesome! works fine. thanks. One more think I should ask: what is the technical explanation for white-space: nowrap;? what does is do basically?

Comment: Using the CSS "white-space: nowrap;" tells the element to not wrap any of the content to the next line, no matter what. You can play around with this concept if you want using plain text inside a <p> tag. Just copy and paste a large amount of text in there with and without the "white-space:nowrap" CSS to see what it does.